# .NET 4.5 File.Copy ok, but file does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

strange behaviour in our production environment, these days.
I have the following:

```
try {
    var sourcePath = ... // my source path
    var destinationPath = ... // guess what? You're right, my destination path

    File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
    Log.Debug(string.Format("Image {0} copied successfully", imagename));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    // exception handling
}
```

Both source and destination path are on a network share, a folder on an other (virtual) machine with a large number of files (> 500k).
From the last 2 days, the code above runs, logs the last line (the one stating that image  have been copied), but if I check in the destination folder, the supposed destination file does not exist.

I thought that for any I/O error File.Copy would raise an exception, so this thing is driving me mad.
Please note that other code parts that write files in that folder are working correctly. Also, note that all files names are unique (business code not included for brevity is making sure of that), and I think an exception would be thrown or the file would be at least overwritten, in that case.

Has anyone faced the same problem? Possible causes? Any solution?

**EDIT 2016-07-01 15:12 (GMT+0200)**

Ok, folks, apparently files aren't being deleted at all... simply for apparently no reason at all, after they are copied they're left open in read+write mode from the client connected user.
I found this trying running the reader application on my computer, in debug mode, and trying to open one of the files i knew that were copied recently.
I got an exception stating that the file was opened by someone else, and that seemed weird to me.
Opening Computer Management in the remote server (the one which stores the files), then going to Shared Folders > Open Files, I found that the file was left open in read+write mode from the impersonated user that the web application that copies the files is impersonating to do that job.
Also a whole bunch of other files where in the same conditions, and many others where open in read mode.
I found also in Shared Folders > Sessions, an astronomical long list of session of the impersonated user, all with long idle time.
Since impersonation is used only to copy the files, and then is disposed, I shouldn't expect that, right?

I think maybe there is a problem in the way we impersonate the user during file copy, linked to the large number of files in the destination folder.
I'll check that.

**END EDIT**

Thanks,

Claudio Valerio

Comment: Maybe someone/something is deleting the file after they get copied?

Comment: Hi Matteo, thanks for commenting.
Sadly no, there is not any line of code that deletes from that specific folder, and no one can access via Windows Explorer but me and my coworkers (no FTP access).

Comment: Maybe your `destinationPath` isn't what you think it is in certain cases.  Perhaps you should log that too.

Comment: Hi Charles,
The destination path is always a specific, existing folder (100% sure) combined with an unique file name.
Besides, this code runs on a small bunch of image files each time, and in a single bunch one or two files are copied correcly and exist.

Comment: Also source file exists, obviously (otherwise i should get a FileNotFoundException, as per documentation).

Comment: do you have permissions to copy the file.. ? I mean the running instanse of VS?

Comment: Hi Aswartha, yes, the application (it's a web application running for the past 2 years and half) has the rights to do anything on that folder, also other parts of the same app that write files in that specific folder are currently working perfectly.
Also, if the application lacked in permission, i would get an UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: Could you run into path length issues? Log your destination paths to gether with your file names and check their lengths.

Comment: Hi LocEngineer, no, path length is always the same:

\\10.90.0.10\ABCDEFGHI\ContentFiles\Content\DealImage\{imageGUID}.JPG

Since GUID have fixed length, the path length is always 94.
And in that case i should have a PathTooLongException.

Comment: Just a wild guess: are you  sure you generate a new guid for each file? Maybe you accidentally overwrite the file with the next one?

Comment: The GUID corresponds to the one of that single file on the sql server database. The field is the primary key of that table, and the record is inserted before the copy. A duplicated entry would make the database insert fail (primary key violation), so I'm pretty sure that guid are unique.
I've just added a log row for the source and destination path and a check if file exists after copy. Let's see what happens...

Comment: Why not log this and then review the logged results after you notice that more files are "deleted/disappearing" as it is the actual destination that you are interested in? `Log.Debug(string.Format("Image '{0}' copied successfully", destinationPath));`

Comment: Hmm... `maybe there is a problem in the way we impersonate the user during file copy` - I would rather suspect there is something wrong with your app not releasing the files. Make sure you have your file accesses in `using` blocks wherever possible, to make sure the process is properly disposed when no longer needed.

Comment: Add to the production code a `File.Exists(destination)` assert after the copy. If this returns anything but false that would be very curious. My guess: It returns true and proves that the problem is elsewhere. You also can add a `new FileStream(Open, RW, Share.None).Dispose()` to prove that no open handles are left. My guess: This check will pass.

Comment: Hi usr, yep, that's exactly what i did, and yep, you won a pizza pie the first time you come near Milan ;)
Read the edit in the question, turns out the files weren't missing at all, just unreadable due to be opened by someone else (aka the user/process that copied the files themselves!).
For what reason the file handlers aren't released (that's the problem, I think) after the File.Copy finishes, I can't tell...

Comment: Next time, use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I think.
My problem was the code used for impersonating the user with write permissions on the destination folder.
(In my defence, all this project have been inherited from previous software company, and it's pretty massive, so keeping an eye on everything isn't that easy)

The impersonation process was wrapped in a class implementing IDisposable

```
public class Impersonator :
    IDisposable
{
    public Impersonator()
    {
        string userName = // get username from config
        string password = // get password from config
        string domainName = // get domain from config
        ImpersonateValidUser(userName, domainName, password);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UndoImpersonation();
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int LogonUser(
        string lpszUserName,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int DuplicateToken(
        IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(
        IntPtr handle);

    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    private void ImpersonateValidUser(
        string userName,
        string domain,
        string password)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            if (RevertToSelf())
            {
                if (LogonUser(
                    userName,
                    domain,
                    password,
                    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                    ref token) != 0)
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(token);
            }
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UndoImpersonation()
    {
        if (impersonationContext != null)
        {
            impersonationContext.Undo();
        }
    }

    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

}
```

This class is used this way:

```
using(new Impersonator())
{
    // do stuff with files in here
}
```

My suspect was that closing the handlers of the impersonated user, somehow, it could break something in the way that windows handles file open by the impersonated user through a network share, as in my case, leaving shared files open in read+write mode, preventing any other process/user to open them.

I modified the Impersonator class as follows:

```
public class Impersonator :
    IDisposable
{
    public Impersonator()
    {
        string userName = // get username from config
        string password = // get password from config
        string domainName = // get domain from config
        ImpersonateValidUser(userName, domainName, password);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UndoImpersonation();
        impersonationContext.Dispose();
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int LogonUser(
        string lpszUserName,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int DuplicateToken(
        IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(
        IntPtr handle);

    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    private void ImpersonateValidUser(
        string userName,
        string domain,
        string password)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;
        token = IntPtr.Zero;
        tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            if (RevertToSelf())
            {
                if (LogonUser(
                    userName,
                    domain,
                    password,
                    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                    ref token) != 0)
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    private void UndoImpersonation()
    {
        try
        {
            if (impersonationContext != null)
            {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(token);
            }
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
            }
        }
    }

    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
    private IntPtr token;
    private IntPtr tokenDuplicate;

}
```

Basically I moved the handlers closing in the UndoImpersonation method. Also I had a doubt about leaving the impersonationContext not explicitly disposed, si I disposed it in the Dispose method of the Impersonator class.

Since I put in production this update, I hadn't any other issue with this code, and not any other shared file left open in read+write mode on the destination server.
Maybe not the optimal solution (I still have a whole bunch of sessions in Computer Management > Shared Folders > Sessions, but this seems not harming the system, for now.

If anyone have some additional comment, suggestion or depth study about this situation, I will be please to read.

Thanks,

Claudio